# Are we able to change the font of the console?

Tags: python

I was working on some code and I had a question pop up. How could I change the font, size or things like that of a user input? I was just testing out a question with some simple code:

```
Change_font = input(‘Enter some words: ’)

print(Change_font)
```

How to change the font of the user input above? I don’t really have any uses for this now, but I think I might later. (I think this is possible in html, but I’m wondering if its possible in other languages, just for beginners.)

I have tried some arbitrary things (it sounded correct… :/) like .changefont() or things like that, but I can’t find anything.

You know how it is when you have a burning question that you can’t find the answer to. (To clarify, i’m not asking to like change the settings, but actual code. Thanks!)

Comment: Don't. I had to waste time the other day installing a different terminal because some script decided to change the windows console font   https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/367 Respect the user's choices.

Comment: Are you using your OS console/terminal for python or IDLE that comes bundled with Python? Both have their own customization options, often found in a settings page within the app. Both would have font settings.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering about if you could change it with code, but these are all helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's out of control of the program showing its output in the terminal emulator.

So, as long as you're using a console to interact with the user, you will have to use whatever that console gives you.

A few things are indeed manipulable: for example, some consoles support setting colors. But that will need some nasty terminal emulator-specific tricks. It's probably not what you want to do: if you want the capabilities of graphical interfaces, go for graphical interfaces. Pygtk and others make that feasible.